# Invalid type: JSON.createGenerator

Tags: apex, json, apexrest, compile-error

We have the following:

- Source SFDC Org: making a REST Callout towards SFDC Target Org
- Target SFDC Org: Custom PUT Webservice being referenced from the Source SFDC Org

**Source SFDC Org**
Future method making a callout towards the Target org Webservice. But we need to generate a specific payload. Thus we need to create a JSONGenerator instance using JSONGenerator gen = new JSON.createGenerator(true); However, upon saving it's giving us the error **Invalid type: JSON.createGenerator**

Structure of the class looks like this:

```
public class className {
  @Future(callout=true)
  public static void doTheCallout() {
   JSONGenerator gen = new JSON.createGenerator(true);

    gen.writeStartObject();
    // creation of the payload
    gen.writeEndObject();
  }
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Check if you have any class name with `JSON`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [method is static](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm) - its a factory for creating instances - so you need this code that does not include a `new`:

```
JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);
```

In your code the compiler thinks you are trying to create an instance of a class called `createGenerator` nested inside a class called `JSON`.

Note that it is usually easier to create JSON by creating a graph of simple Apex objects or by using maps and then using the `JSON.serialize` method.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the `new` keyword. It should only be used when calling constructors, not for calling methods.

**Works**

```
JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);
```

**Fails**

```
JSONGenerator gen = new JSON.createGenerator(true);
```